# Set parent Control to another control

Tags: vba, excel, controls

I need to set a parent Control to another control using the VBA code.
Actually i am looping to create differents controls dynamically and i want now to link them by child-parent.

Do someone has an idea ?

Comment: What kind of control? Textbox? ComboBox? ListBox? What do you intend to do with them? Do you have code you can post to show where the problem is? More information please!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You provide so little information in your question that it is difficult to guess your objective.

However, I am guessing that you want to record that Control Xxxxx is the parent of control Yyyyy where the definition of “parent” has nothing to do with Excel’s definition of parent.  I am further guessing you do not know how to access controls by number.

The macro below lists the name, type and top position of every control on a form by its index number within the collection `Controls`.  Any property of a control is accessible in this way.  If control Xxxxx is the parent of control Yyyyy, you can scan the collection to find their index numbers when the form loads and record this information for use when required.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim InxCtrl As Long
  Dim LenNameMax As Long
  Dim LenTypeMax As Long

  LenNameMax = 0
  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    If LenNameMax < Len(Controls(InxCtrl).Name) Then
      LenNameMax = Len(Controls(InxCtrl).Name)
    End If
    If LenTypeMax < Len(TypeName(Controls(InxCtrl))) Then
      LenTypeMax = Len(TypeName(Controls(InxCtrl)))
    End If
  Next

  Debug.Print PadR("Name", LenNameMax) & "|" & PadR("Type", LenTypeMax) & "|     Top"
  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    Debug.Print PadR(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, LenNameMax) & "|" & _
                PadR(TypeName(Controls(InxCtrl)), LenTypeMax) & "|" & _
                PadL(Format(Controls(InxCtrl).Top, "#,###.00"), 8)
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to set a parent to a control.  For example i have a control which is a frame and another which is a textbox, i need to set the frame as parent of the textbox.

Comment: @Prog_is_life.  When designing a form, you define a Frame as the parent of a Textbox by placing the Textbox within the Frame.  The property Parent is described as readonly in the documentation so I doubt you can associate a Textbox and a Frame at runtime with VBA.

Comment: Yes i finally found how to do .. i just needed "examplectrl.controls.add(..)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function where i create a new control and i set some values. And the last assignment is where i want to set the parent
          Public Function apply_change(ihm_f, oNode, iMyName$, project$)

```
Dim new_elem
Dim oSubNodes As IXMLDOMNode

If oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Type").Text <> "Page" Then
    If (oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Type").Text = "RefEdit") Then

        Set new_elem = ihm_f.Designer.Controls.Add("RefEdit.Ctrl", oNode.nodeName, True)

    Else
        Set new_elem = ihm_f.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms." & oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Type").Text & ".1", oNode.nodeName, True)
    End If
    With new_elem
        On Error Resume Next
        .Width = oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Width").Text
        .Top = oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Top").Text
        .Left = oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Left").Text
        .Height = oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Height").Text
        Set .Parent = get_parent(oNode.ParentNode.nodeName, oNode, ihm_f)
    End With
    If oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Type").Text = "MultiPage" Then
    Call new_elem.Pages.Remove(0)
    Call new_elem.Pages.Remove(0)
     For Each oSubNodes In oNode.ChildNodes()
        Call new_elem.Pages.Add(oSubNodes.BaseName, oSubNodes.Attributes.getNamedItem("Caption").Text, oSubNodes.Attributes.getNamedItem("Index").Text)
     Next oSubNodes
    End If
End If
Set apply_change = ihm_f
End Function
```

The getparent function return a Controle which can be anything .. like textbox or combo box etc..

Comment: Is this non-functioning code for which you seek help?  If so, it should be within your question.